# ng-mouseenter not working inside a AngularJs Factory

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, mouseevent, onmouseover, angularjs-factory

I am trying to implement tooltip type feature inside my factory, but am facing issue in calling the  ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave events as its inside the factory.
Kindly guide how to proceed.

Code:
HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <title>Mouseevent - Second</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
        .red{
            background-color: red;
        }
        .show{
            background: lightgray;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 98;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="demoController">
        <div ng-bind-html="fromFactory"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp',[])
app.controller('demoController',function($scope,$sce,hoverFactory){
$scope.fromFactory = hoverFactory.demo();
$scope.onMouseEnter = function(evt){
  $scope.hovered = true;
  $scope.mouse = {
               'left': evt.pageX + 10  + 'px' ,
               'top': evt.pageY + 10 + 'px'
  }
};
$scope.onMouseLeave = function(){
    $scope.hovered = false;
  }
});

app.factory('hoverFactory',function($sce){
  return{
    demo:function(){
    var template = '<div  ng-class="{red: hover}" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event)"'+ 
       'ng-mouseleave="onMouseLeave()" > "Hover mouse on me to make tooltip move! "</div>' +
       '<div class="show" ng-show="hovered" ng-style="mouse" ng-init= "hover=false">movable tooltip</div>';

      var result = $sce.trustAsHtml(template);
      return result;
    }
  }
});
```

Please guide people, i am stuck

Comment: What are you trying to do? You need to $compile any html in order for angular to wire up events and stuff ... Plus, it's not something you would do in a factory

Comment: i do agree with you, here i am trying to add the tooltip feature on an existing code.
i  am not sure how to call the function to get x and y co-ordinates for tooltip

Answer (score 0):

You should use a directive base on attribute tooltips-target. There you can access the scope of the element and apply any jquery tooltips you need :

```
<div  tooltips-target >lorem</div>
```

and you create the directive

```
app.directive('tooltipsTarget', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element) {
      $(element).myTooltips();
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle link :

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djlahmid/6xukcejy/1/)

Comment: i tried adding directive in template of factory but its not calling the directive

Comment: I added a JsFiddle descriptions.